# Stopping rpmbuild from re-writing Requires

Tags: python, rpm, rhel, rpmbuild

I am building a binary RPM from a Python package. The package uses a custom `.spec` file, and this is a hard requirement. (`python setup.py bdist_rpm` is simply not flexible enough.)

For instance, a snippet of the `.spec` file looks like this:

```
%else
%if 0%{?rhel} >= 7

BuildRequires: python2-devel
BuildRequires: python-setuptools

Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
Requires: python2-boto >= 2.5.0
Requires: python2-cryptography < 3
```

The process is to:

- Create an sdist and put it under SOURCES (`%{_sourcedir}`)
- Call `rpmbuild -bb <path-to.spec>`

The meat of the spec file looks like this:

```
%prep
%setup -q -n %{name}-%{unmangled_version}

%build
%if %{with_python2}
%py2_build
%endif
%if %{with_python3}
%py3_build
%endif

%install
%if %{with_python2}
%{__python2} setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed -O1 --root=%{buildroot} --record=INSTALLED_FILES
%endif
%if %{with_python3}
%{__python3} setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed -O1 --root=%{buildroot} --record=INSTALLED_FILES
%endif
```

For simplification, we can forget about the conditional checks and just specify a single unconditional requires:

```
Requires: PyYAML
```

**The problem is `rpmbuild` somewhere mangles the `Requires:` to a completely different set of requirements.**

```
$ rpm -qp --requires /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/path-to-project3.0.0-1.noarch.rpm
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
python(abi) = 2.7
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

with the `PyYAML` requirement conspicuously missing.

The build occurs on a CentOS 7 Docker container, and no matter what I try, I cannot get `rpmbuild` to leave the `Requires:` sections alone.  I've attempted:

- `%undefine __pythondist_requires`
- `setup.py --quiet egg_info --egg-base /tmp sdist`

All to no avail.

How do I get `rpmbuild` to just stay true to the actual `.spec` file?

---

#### MVCE

I've built an MVCE project at https://github.com/bsolomon1124/test-so-7954504. The README there contains complete instructions to reproduce, also shown here:

Clone the project.

Run container:

```sh
docker container run -it --rm --volume "$(pwd)":/io --workdir /io --entrypoint bash centos:7
```

Set up and build RPM that will get put in `dist/`:

```sh
$ yum update -y
$ yum install -y make
$ make setup_build
$ make rpm
```

Check requires, see those from `.spec` file are ignored:

```sh
[root@xxxxxx io]# rpm -qp --requires dist/myproj-0.1-1.noarch.rpm
python(abi) = 2.7
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that produces this behavior when built without changes. Can be a completely empty package, no need to have files in it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy added

Comment: Snooping around under /usr/lib/rpm now, looks like `/usr/lib/rpm/fileattrs/python.attr` and `/usr/lib/rpm/pythondeps.sh` might be useful...

Comment: Looks like `%define __python_requires %{nil}` gets me halfway there, but still drops *all* Requires from the input specfile and just leaves me with the rpmlib stuff.

Comment: Thank you for that -- having a good reproducer makes a prima facia case that digging in is going to be worth the time. If I'm still in a mentally-functioning state when my workday ends, I'll look into it this evening.

Comment: Got this working, but can't debug back _how_ I got it working :) So, don't spend you time on this one. It was some combination of `-ba`, removing `--noclean`, `__python_requires`, and/or `AutoReqProv`.

Comment: You still did not provided full project.spec. I have a feeling that you are putting the requires in wrong place (inside some %if).